# Dropping table removes foreign key constraints from child table silently

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

This in in db2 on the iSeries.
We have two tables, a master table and a child table where the child has a foreign key constraint to the master. 
We can drop the master table and what is happening is that it is dropping the table and removing the constraint from the child silently.
It should be stopping the drop because of the constraint.

Is this an iSeries configuration setting?

Answer (score 4):

if you want the behaviour mentioned in your question,  consider using the syntax `DROP TABLE ... RESTRICT`

According to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzdropst.htm) the RESTRICT clause:

> Specifies that the table cannot be dropped if it is referenced in a
>   constraint, index, trigger, variable, view, XSR object, or
>   materialized query table.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll give this a go.Do you know if there is there a way to set this as the default setting? Maybe in one of the SYSVALs or similiar? (edit: That link doesn't work for me, I've tried googling but get a 443).

Comment: No, this can not be made a default. The link works for me.